# Google Chrome Extension: captureVisibleTab problem

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to capture the current visible tab but I'm receiving undefined.
The following code is executing when the extension's icon is pressed. When the alert is called I see *undefined* instead of an URL.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {            
  chrome.windows.getCurrent(function (win) {    
      chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(win.id,{"format":"png"}, function(imgUrl) {
            alert(imgUrl);                                            
      });    
  });    
});
```

What should I do to get the URL of the captured image?
Can someone please help me out with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I guess your code is taken from the example given on the Chrome Extension Website and yes, it's buggy.

Change the permission attribute inside the manifest.json to this:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs"
    ,"<all_urls>"
]
```

Cheers,
David

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it did not return undefined for me. The following is the code.
Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

Background.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {            
  chrome.windows.getCurrent(function (win) {    
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(win.id,{"format":"png"}, function(imgUrl) {
        alert(imgUrl);                                            
    });    
  });    
 });
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, thank you! maybe there is something with my browser. I'll reinstall it.