# chrome.windows dosen't have "getLastFocused"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am having strange error in my chrome extension, I can see that for some of my users they get the next error - 
*Cannot call method 'getLastFocused' of undefined*.
This is my code: 

`// In background.html

chrome.windows.getLastFocused(function(win){ });`

I can't recreate this problem, I see the problem happens in chrome 9-12. Someone have idea why it happens? how to reproduce?

***Edit: I have the same problem with "getAll" function***

Comment: Do you have the `tabs` permission?

Comment: Yes, I have the tabs permission.

Comment: Ask those users to update to newer versions. It's literally two clicks. Alternatively, you might try adding a url specification in the permission entry in the manifest - I'm not sure but I remember reading that it used to be buggy without it. Like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453459/google-chrome-extension-capturevisibletab-problem

Comment: You think this is happening because they are using old version of chrome? because in chrome 12 I see there is "chrome.windows.getLastFocused" function.

Comment: I have no idea, I'm taking stabs in the dark, although it's a reasonable conclusion if you cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: ok, thanks :) I will be happy for more answers/explainations